# When does Google Analytics record a pageview if it is triggered by Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, page-views

For general user, page view is calculated when page is load. I understand that but I want to ask from web developer's perspective.

When is page view incremented:

- when GTM tracking script, in head tag, is executed by browser? (which happens before the actual page is loaded)
- when DOMContentLoaded event is fired on window?
- when load event is fired on window (this is when complete page is loaded including images and remaining scripts at the bottom of body tag)
  Considering above questions, I want to know how exactly page view works.

Comment: GTM adds the tracking script, but that script still has to run and contact the GA servers.